# how to unescape html entities **except** &lt; &gt; &amp; &quot; &apos; in java

Tags: java, html, escaping, html-entities

I have html input in utf-8. In this input accented characters are presented as html entities. For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>&aacute;rv&iacute;zt&#x0171;r&#x0151;&lt;b</body>
</html>
```

My goal is to "canonicalize" the html by replacing html entities with utf-8 characters where possible in Java. In other words, replace all entities *except* `&lt; &gt; &amp; &quot; &apos;`.

The goal:

```
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>árvíztűrő&lt;b</body>
</html>
```

I need this to make it easier to compare htmls in tests, and to be easier to read for the naked eye (lots of escaped accented characters makes it very hard to read).

I don't care cdata sections (there's no cdata in the inputs).

I have tried JSOUP (https://jsoup.org/) and Apache's Commons Text (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/) unsuccessfully:

```
public void test() throws Exception {

    String html = 
            "<html><head><META http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">" +
            "</head><body>&aacute;rv&iacute;zt&#x0171;r&#x0151;&lt;b</body></html>";

    // this is not good, keeps only the text content
    String s1 = Jsoup.parse(html).text();
    System.out.println("s1: " + s1);

    // this is better, but it unescapes the &lt; which is not what I want
    String s2 = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(html);
    System.out.println("s2: " + s2);
}
```

The StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4() is almost what I need, but it unfortunately unescapes the < also:

```
<body>árvíztűrő<b</body>
```

How should I do it?

Here is a minimal demonstration: https://github.com/riskop/html_utf8_canon.git

Answer (score 3):

Looking into the Commons Text source it is clear that StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4() delegates work to an AggregateTranslator, which is composed of 4 CharSequenceTranslator:

```
new AggregateTranslator(
        new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.BASIC_UNESCAPE),
        new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.ISO8859_1_UNESCAPE),
        new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.HTML40_EXTENDED_UNESCAPE),
        new NumericEntityUnescaper()
);
```

I need **only three** of the translators to fullfill my goal.

So this is it:

```
    // this is what I needed!
    String s3 = new AggregateTranslator(
            new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.ISO8859_1_UNESCAPE),
            new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.HTML40_EXTENDED_UNESCAPE),
            new NumericEntityUnescaper()
    ).translate(html);
    System.out.println("s3: " + s3);
```

Whole method:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {

    String html = 
            "<html><head><META http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">" +
            "</head><body>&aacute;rv&iacute;zt&#x0171;r&#x0151;&lt;b</body></html>";

    // this is what I needed!
    CharSequenceTranslator UNESCAPE_HTML_EXCEPT_BASIC = new AggregateTranslator(
            new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.ISO8859_1_UNESCAPE),
            new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.HTML40_EXTENDED_UNESCAPE),
            new NumericEntityUnescaper()
    );

    String s3 = UNESCAPE_HTML_EXCEPT_BASIC.translate(html);
    System.out.println("s3: " + s3);

}
```

Result:

```
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>árvíztűrő&lt;b</body>
</html>
```